# How to configure ctags in Kate?

Tags: kate

I use Kubuntu LTS as my OS. **How to use ctags in Kate?**

I selected ctags in the plugin manager window, so that now, by right clicking on any word of my code few ctags options appear. Namely: "go to declaration", "go to definition", "look up". But choosing one of these options nothing happens.

I think I did something wrong in the configuration: what should I write in the "ctags database" and in the "index targets" boxes?

Answer (score 6):

Once you have CTags installed

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

Activate the plugin by going to <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Configure Kate...</kbd>

Then when the window pops up, click <kbd>Application</kbd> -> <kbd>Plugins</kbd> and check "CTags"

[image: screenshot of kate plugins]

Next in Kate's <kbd>Index Targets</kbd> tab pane, click <kbd>Add</kbd> and enter the `/path/to/project/root`, then click <kbd>Update Index</kbd>

[image: screenshot of "Index Targets" pane]

Now you will be able to use the CTags.

---

**Notice** the <kbd>Database</kbd> tab pane is where you can set the CTags command. See [the man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ctags) for options. Generally, I like to exclude my dependency package folders by adding:

```
--exclude=vendor --exclude=node_modules
```

No need to put anything in the "CTags Database File" field because Kate will automatically generate this file when you click <kbd>Update Index</kbd>

[image: screenshot database tab pane]

---

**Note** that you can, but *do not **need*** to create a `.kateproject` file to use the CTags.

Comment: Instead of `exuberant-ctags` now use `sudo apt install universal-ctags`.
Also don't overlook option `--options`. Command `ctags --options=~/ctags.options.sh` make things much easier when you try to pass 20+ options.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to make sure you have ctags installed:

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

Create a ".kateproject" project file in the folder where your code is 
(see http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=93570 for more info):

e.g. This the contents of one I set up recently:

```
{
  "name": "Report Downloader"
, "files": [ { "directory": ".",
      "filters": [
    "*.php",
    "*.css", 
    "*.js", 
    "*.html"
    "*.py"
      ], 
    "recursive": 1 } 
  ]
}
```

Then open a file within the project (you don't open the project directly) and ctags should start working.

Comment: The `.kateproject` file is no longer needed with the current version of Kate in the trusted Ubuntu repo.