# How do I update CTags in Kate?

Tags: kate

I am new to CTags, and I tried it out for the first time a while back. It worked fine in Kate, I was able to use the keyboard shortcuts to jump to function definitions.

Now I'm trying it out again on the same system. I've opened up a new project, I've run `ctags` and it's created the `tags` file in the project root directory. I've confirmed it works in vim and I can jump between definitions as expected.

When I open Kate, I add the tags file (`/home/jeff/project/tags`) to the index targets, and click <kbd>Update Index</kbd> but now when I try to goto definition, it's always:

> No hits found

I've also tried updating the database, and it's created a `session_db_` with today's date.

I also tried creating the `.kateproject` file as proposed by an answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/383762/453746), which is something I didn't have to do last time it worked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, instead of adding the `tags` file (`/home/jeff/project/tags`) to the target index, I was supposed to just add the directory that the `tags` file is in (`/home/jeff/project/`) - not the `tags` file itself.

After changing the target index to `/home/jeff/project/` and updating the index, then I am easily able to hop to definitions like I expect.